# calling Keras predict on CNN simply returns the input

Tags: python, keras, regression, conv-neural-network

Based on a matrix, I am trying to approximate a value (regression). However, the CNN always predicts a **matrix** which is **identical** to the input of `predict`.
I am not getting any errors.

The data (matrices) used for training are stored in a numpy array but I only have around 9000 samples available. The values for each matrix are stored in a one dimensional array (one value for each matrix).

This is my model:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='selu', input_shape=(8, 8, 1)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='selu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=2, activation='selu'),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')
])

optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['mean_squared_error'])

model.fit(matrices, values, epochs=10)

test_loss = model.evaluate(test_boards,  test_values, verbose=2)
```

Example output when calling `prediction = model.predict(some_matrix)` can be found below. In this case `some_matrix` is equal to the output below.

```
[[  51.    0.   33.    0.  100.   33.    0.   51.]
 [  10.   10.   10.    0.    0.   10.   10.   10.]
 [   0.    0.   32.    0.    0.   32.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.   88.   10.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.  -10.    0.  -32.    0.    0.]
 [ -10.  -10.  -10.    0.    0.  -10.  -10.  -10.]
 [ -51.  -32.  -33.  -88. -100.  -33.    0.  -51.]]
```

What am I missing to get a single value as output? Or at least a modified version of the input?

**Edit**:

[My matrix data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Nuytemans-Dieter/Practicum-AI/master/Lab%204%20-%20Chess%20Agent/data/boardData.txt) (did not fit in a free pastebin account, sorry)

[My values](https://pastebin.com/62LEfEDz)

[An example google colab file](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1go7-fWWCGDfNVQrwLV6kdHYmhYBI-ygw)

I did not find a way to provide the data into Google Colab and include them in the link, I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

I did get an error this time which I did not get when running the code in my own environment. This is definitely the issue but I am still unaware of how to fix this.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-595f98617fa0> in <module>()
     97   [ -51,   -32,  -33,  -88, -100,  -33,    0,  -51,]])
     98 print(test_boards[0])
---> 99 prediction = model.predict(test_boards[0])
    100 print("Prediction:")
    101 print(prediction)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    561                            ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    562                            str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 563                            'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    564         if not check_batch_axis:
    565           data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_12_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (8, 8, 1)
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem, can you provide sample input and output? It cannot be predicting a 8x8x1 matrix as the model has a single neuron. Make sure you are using the right model.

Comment: Thank you for responding, that is exactly what I thought as well. The matrix at the lowest code block is what I used as parameter in `predict`. But it returns the exact same matrix, unchanged.

Comment: Well to be honest I am skeptic that it is happening as you describe it, if you make a self-containing example we can run, we can validate what you say.

Comment: here is a link to colab https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pNgiqe5r-w6P7O1H3azOlbgy16g99Xxz

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro That is only fair. Now I do seem to be getting an error, which is likely the cause. I still don't understand what's wrong though. The model trained fine and even evaluated its test data just fine. The error is thrown when predicting (please see my edit).

Comment: You need to add the samples dimension, so your data is (1, 8, 8, 1), as you only have one sample. You can do this with np.expand_dims or np.reshape

Comment: @DieterNuytemans What do you understand from that error?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro that seemed to be the issue indeed. Earlier I had given predict a parameter of `batch_size=1` so I thought that dimension was added automatically. It works as expected now, thank you!

Comment: @AMC I was confused by the reason the error was thrown, as the training data was used just fine and I thought I had given `predict` an input of the same size but that was not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the batch size dimension to the test sample.

`some_matrix = some_matrix[np.newaxis,:,:,np.newaxis]`

Comment: That did not work but someone gave a working solution in the comments of the question: I'll give it here as well for potential future visitors. the shape had to be (1,8,8,1). (2x a 1 for dimension and #channels). The data was reshaped by `numpy.reshape(1,8,8,1)`.
I will accept your reply as answer though, as you found the issue as well.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. I think I know where my answer went wrong and have tried to correct it above.